# OR/AND operation on lists in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, rosette

I want to understand what `and` and `or` represent in Racket when used with lists. When I do something like this -

```
> (or `(1 2) `(1 3))
'(1 2)
```

What is the result representing? I thought when we use or with two lists we would get a union of the lists. That is clearly not what is happening here. So, I thought it is interpreted as boolean values and that is why `(1 2) is not a false value. Hence, the result is `(1 2). But what about this? -

```
> (and `(1 2) `(1 3))
'(1 3)
```

How can I justify this?

Comment: There are many "Racket" languages. Your examples show the standard [Scheme interpretation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_idx_120), which is inherited by `#lang racket`, explained and justified in its [excellent documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html#%28part._and%2Bor%29). Documentation can be accessed from DrRacket by right-clicking on a selection and choosing "Search in Help Desk for..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` is looking for the first truthy value, checking arguments from left to right. Every value other than `#false` is truthy. If any is found, it's returned. In your example, `'(1 2)` is the first truthy value from the left, so it's returned.

`Or` called with no arguments returns `#false`, because no truthy values were found:

```
> (or)
#f
```

`And` checks whether all values are truthy, so it has to examine all of them, going from left to the right, and it can return `#false` (if any `#false` is found) or, if all values are truthy, last of them. In your example, `'(1 3)` is the last truthy value, so it's returned.

`And` called with no arguments returns `#true`, because no `#false` was found:

```
> (and)
#t
```

Read also the docs about [`or`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._or%29%29) and [`and`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._and%29%29).

By the way, there is a difference between `'` and `` ` ``. First one is [`quote`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quote.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._quote%29%29), the second one is [`quasiquote`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._quasiquote%29%29). In this very example, it doesn't matter, but you should know the difference between them.
And if you were really looking for union function, check [`racket/set`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html) library:

```
(require racket/set)
(set-union (set 1 2) (set 1 3))
=> (set 1 3 2)
```